# Trouble on Class instance

Tags: ios, swift

My purpose is when a button is pressed in **ViewController 2** the screen will be dismissed and I'll fill my delegates with UIColor / UIImage, correct? Ok, then after view dismiss the **ViewController 1** will set the background color to red. However, I got in trouble when I tried to instantiate the "Escolha VC" in **ViewController 1**. I'll post both classes above:

***ViewController 1***

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var labelNome: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func BotaoStart(_ sender: Any) {

        let selectionVC = EscolhaVC()

   selectionVC.selectionDelegate = self //I got no crashes, 
  //but the problem is that a black screen comes in instead "EscolhaVC"

        present(selectionVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

extension ViewController:DidselectInformationDelegate {
    func selectedOptions(imagem: UIImage, cor: UIColor) {
        self.imageView.image = imagem
        self.view.backgroundColor = cor
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

***ViewController 2***

```
import UIKit

protocol DidselectInformationDelegate {
    func selectedOptions(imagem:UIImage, cor:UIColor)
}

class EscolhaVC: UIViewController {


    var selectionDelegate:DidselectInformationDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }


    @IBAction func botaoLadoBom(_ sender: Any) {
        selectionDelegate?.selectedOptions(imagem: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ladoBom"), cor: .green)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }



    @IBAction func botaoLadoNegro(_ sender: Any) {
        selectionDelegate?.selectedOptions(imagem: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ladoNegro"), cor: .red)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "to conform delegates?" What do you mean by "developed as full code?" Do you have an example piece of code that you're struggling with?

Comment: Hello Rob. Conform I meant like (delegate = self) and made as "full code" is a project without Storyboard. My question is: How can I instantiate ViewControllers from a different way instead of the way above?

Comment: With `let vc = ViewControllerType(parameters...)`. I'm not clear what the question is. Is there a reason you're trying to remove the Storyboard?

Comment: Yes, because I do have other projects that don’t use Storyboard

Comment: What if I don’t have any parameters in the other Class? Let’s say I just have a protocol in there. How would I instantiate this Class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, initialization is a very extensive topic in Swift. Check out [this documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html) for a full explanation on the subject. But as a brief summary, you just have to call whatever parameters are required in any of the `init`'s of a type (class or struct). As an example, think of the following class:

```
class Foo {
  let a: Int
  let b: Int

  init() {
    a = 0
    b = 0
  }

  init(a: Int, b: Int) {
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
  }
}
```

You have two ways of instantiating a `Foo` object. Either by `let foo = Foo()` or something like `let foo = Foo(a: 10, b: 20)`. It doesn't matter if it's a subclass of some other class, like a `UIViewController` subclass. It doesn't matter whether it contains or not a property whose type is a protocol. Unless your `UIViewController` subclass defines custom initializers, you can instantiate it by simply:

```
let selectionVC = EscolhaVC()
```

Then just set whatever other necessary property afterwards:

```
selectionVC.selectionDelegate = self
```

That's pretty straightforward for any type. The thing is every property in a type must be initialized at instantiation. That means non-optional types must have their values set. This is basically what that document I linked is about.

**EDIT**

Based on your edit, that's not an issue about instantiation, but about stylizing your `EscolhaVC`. When you instantiate from storyboard, you get a view controller with all the views, colors, etc you defined in interface builder. But you need to that by yourself if you're instantiating the view controller by its initializer. For instance, try to set your `EscolhaVC`'s view background color do something else and you will see that's all good:

```
class EscolhaVC: UIViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .red
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello @ajeferson. I just updated the code, let's see if I got to clarify my error. Could you check below, please? BTW, thank your so much for you answer!

Comment: Sure. That's actually not a matter of instantiation, but how you setup your `EscolhaVC` view controller. For instance, try to set the background color in the viewDidLoad of `EscolhaVC` (view.backgroundColor = .red).

Comment: My purpose is when a button is pressed in ViewController 2 the screen will be dismissed and I'll fill my delegates, correct? Ok, then after view dismiss the ViewController 1 will set the background color to red. However, I got in trouble when I tried to instantiate the "Escolha VC" in ViewController 1.

Comment: Well, now I'm confused. I notice that in EscolhaVC you have action functions (@IBFunction). You also need to add the targets to those functions programmatically. But for me it looks ok the way you're instantiating EscolhaVC in first view controller.

Comment: I'm telling you, your code is all fine. It's ok to show up a black screen since you're not applying any style or loading the view controller from the interface builder. If you want anything to show up you need to it programmatically? Even the @IBFunctions won't work since they're not bound to anything.

Comment: No, no! But I did, lol. This screen (EscolhaVC) is created on my Storyboard, it has content(Objects and etc)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192158/discussion-between-ajeferson-and-titujow).